# Обновление переменных в get запросе происходит поздно

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Не могу разобраться в чем проблема. Данный код при нажатии на кнопку выполняет прошло действие, т.е. он сравнивает с прошлым значениями переменных. Заметил то, что вывод информации происходит не по порядку.

```
Get test1 = new Get();
    test1.run("http://" + server +"/vend/iszakaz.php?k="+name,
            new okhttp3.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    //todo work with response, parse and etc...
                    r2 = response.body().string();
                    String[] subStr;
                    String delimeter = ";"; // Разделитель
                    subStr = r2.split(delimeter);
                    String c2;
                    c2 = subStr[0];
                    d1 = Integer.parseInt(c2);
                    flag1=1;
                    System.out.print("R=");
                    System.out.println(r2);
                    System.out.print("D=");
                    System.out.println(d1);
                    System.out.print("F=");
                    System.out.println(flag1);
                }
            });
```

Код текст их кода выше выводится в самом конце, хотя должен выводиться раньше, в чем может быть дело. 
Вот весь код:

```
    public void onSave1(View view) {
   // flag1=0;
    System.out.println("Start");

    FileInputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(bytes);
        String text = new String (bytes);
        name = text;
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {

        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finally{

        try{
            if(fin!=null)
                fin.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){

            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    try {
        fin = openFileInput(FILE_NAME1);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(bytes);
        String text = new String (bytes);
        server = text;
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {

        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finally{

        try{
            if(fin!=null)
                fin.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){

            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    Get test1 = new Get();
    test1.run("http://" + server +"/vend/iszakaz.php?k="+name,
            new okhttp3.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    //todo work with response, parse and etc...
                    r2 = response.body().string();
                    String[] subStr;
                    String delimeter = ";"; // Разделитель
                    subStr = r2.split(delimeter);
                    String c2;
                    c2 = subStr[0];
                    d1 = Integer.parseInt(c2);
                    flag1=1;
                    System.out.print("R=");
                    System.out.println(r2);
                    System.out.print("D=");
                    System.out.println(d1);
                    System.out.print("F=");
                    System.out.println(flag1);
                }
            });
    if(d1==0 && flag1==1) {
        System.out.println("d1=0");
        Get test2 = new Get();
        test2.run("http://" + server + "/vend/dbname.php?k=" + name + "&n=1",
                new okhttp3.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        //todo work with response, parse and etc...

                    }
                });
        Get test3 = new Get();
        test3.run("http://" + server + "/vend/idapp.php?k=" + name,
                new okhttp3.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        //todo work with response, parse and etc...
                        r1 = response.body().string();
                        String[] subStr;
                        String delimeter = ";"; // Разделитель
                        subStr = r1.split(delimeter);
                        String c1;
                        c1 = subStr[0];
                        msg = "Спасибо," + c1 + ", Ваш обед заказан";

                    }
                });
        flag1=0;
    } else if (d1==1 && flag1==1) {
        msg = "Вы уже заказали обед";
        flag1=0;
        System.out.print("D1=");
        System.out.println(d1);
    } else if (d1==2 && flag1==1) {
        msg = "Ваша карта не найдена";
        flag1=0;
        System.out.print("D2=");
        System.out.println(d1);
    }

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

Знаю, что код написано криво. Я новичок, пока не разобрался с некоторыми вещами.

Comment: а что конкретно не правильно выводит ?

Comment: Выводит прошлое сформированное сообщение

Comment: то есть этот метод onSave1() несколько раз запускается ?

Comment: Нет, выполняется один раз, я проверял это. К примеру, при нажатии кнопки сразу после запуска строка равна null, хотя всю информацию загрузила на сервер, т.е. зашла во условия

Comment: Извините, не правильно понял ошибку, исправил сообщение

Comment: работа с сетью выполняется в отдельном потоке, это должно натолкнуть на решение проблемы с условиями в одном методе.